Does lack of sleep impact on matching pitch and singing well?
As a beginner, I wanted to ask if it's normal to struggle with pitch matching, singing in tune, and vocal support when I'm tired or sleep-deprived. It feels like I can't hold a pitch, maintain a tune, or even match simple keyboard pitches.
even a song that i could sing properly yesterday seems impossible today that i feel super tired, Is this normal?

It can impact your voice itself, and your vocal mechanisms ability to heal after use. And of course it impacts your cognitive functioning. You can help your voice with things like honey lemon, but while caffeine could help your brain, it can hurt your voice.

I think it's a given that fatigue will affect ANY skill, mental or physical.  So yes, it's normal.
Having said that, one definition of a professional is someone who performs competently even on a bad day!

I’d say a professional is someone who consistently gets enough sleep.

@ToddWilcox I guess you've never worked in Music Theatre!

@ToddWilcox I guess you've never been on tour!
